# Is there a way to stop QEMU from flashing when loading C code from Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, bootloader

I'm creating an [OS that plays snake](https://github.com/skzidev/snake-os), However when I try to load C code, It seemingly restarts.
GDB refused to connect to qemu, so I'm left to my own devices as far as debugging goes.
I can't think of any way to stop it from happening that I haven't tried.

Here's my code in full.

```
[org 0x7c00]

; Load Sectors
mov ah, 0x02
mov al, 0x2
int 0x13

KERNELLOC equ 0x1000
CODESEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATASEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

cli ; Disable Interrupts
lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; GDT start address
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax ; Jump to Protected 32 bit mode
jmp CODESEG:start_protected_mode

gdt_start:
    gdt_null:
        dd 0x0
        dd 0x0

    gdt_code:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10011010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
    
    gdt_data:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10010010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
    gdt_end:

    gdt_descriptor:
        dw gdt_end - gdt_start
        dd gdt_start

[bits 32]
start_protected_mode:
    mov ax, DATASEG
        mov ss, ax
        mov es, ax
        mov fs, ax
        mov gs, ax

        mov ebp, 0x90000
        mov esp, ebp

    jmp KERNELLOC

; Marking as bootable.
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

it's "`jmp KERNELLOC`" that causes the problem.
I have no idea what's causing the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "load sectors" part fails to set up all needed registers. Might be not the only error but is certainly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow [this article](https://dev.to/frosnerd/writing-my-own-boot-loader-3mld) to make adjustments to my code that stops the flickering. After googling around, I was able to adjust my code to work properly. I presume I was reading the sectors incorrectly, and so the code didn't work as it should've.

For Reference, Here is my code

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7C00]

mov [BOOTDRIVE], dl

; call clear_screen ; Clear screen
call load_kernel

load_kernel:
    mov bx, KERNELOFFSET
    mov dh, 0x05
    mov dl, [BOOTDRIVE]
    ; mov dl, 0x80
    call clear_screen     ; Clear Screen
    call disk_load        ; Load From Disk

    mov ah, 0x00          ; Start setting video mode
    mov al, 0x12          ; 640x480 16 color graphics
    int 0x10

    cli                   ; Disable Interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; GDT start address
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax          ; Jump to Protected 32 bit mode
    jmp CODESEG:start_protected_mode

    jmp $

clear_screen:
    pusha

    mov ah, 0x07     ; Scroll al lines; 0 = all
    mov bh, 0x0f     ; white on black
    mov cx, 0x00     ; row=0, col=0
    mov dx, 0x184f   ; row = 24, col = 79
    int 0x10         ; Call interrupt

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, 0x00
    mov bh, 0x00
    int 0x10

    popa
    ret

disk_load:
    pusha
    push dx
    mov ah, 0x02 ; read mode
    mov al, dh   ; read dh number of sects
    mov cl, 0x02 ; read from sect 2 (1 = boot)
    mov ch, 0x00 ; cylinder 0
    mov dh, 0x00 ; head 0

    int 0x13
    jc disk_error

    pop dx
    cmp al, dh

    jne sectors_error
    popa
    ret

disk_error:
    mov ah, '1' ; Error Code
    jmp err_loop
sectors_error:
    mov ah, '2' ; Error Code
    jmp err_loop
err_loop:
    mov dh, ah ; Print Error Message
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 'E'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'r'
    int 0x10
    int 0x10
    mov al, ' '
    int 0x10
    mov al, dh ; Print Error Code
    int 0x10
    
    jmp $ ; create infinite loop

; Constants
KERNELOFFSET equ 0x1000
CODESEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATASEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

gdt_start:
    dq 0x0

    gdt_null:
        dd 0x0
        dd 0x0

    gdt_code:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10011010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
    
    gdt_data:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10010010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
    gdt_end:

    gdt_descriptor:
        dw gdt_end - gdt_start
        dd gdt_start

[bits 32]
start_protected_mode:
    ; Load the kernel
    mov ax, DATASEG
    mov dx, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    
    mov ebp, 0x9000
    mov esp, ebp

    jmp KERNELOFFSET
    jmp $

BOOTDRIVE db 0

; Marking as bootable.
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```